# java.sql.sql.exception :Illegal operation on empty result set

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I have made a simple science quiz java app with 4 frames: Login, Menu, Test, and Result.

The first three frames are working fine but when i click on show result it shows an error. 
This is my code from the Result JFrame. If you want I can send coding of Test JFrame also.

this is my error

> java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:815)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5528)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5448)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getFloat(ResultSetImpl.java:2499)
>           at Test.ResultBTNActionPerformed(Test.java:292)
>           at Test.access$500(Test.java:18)
>           at Test$6.actionPerformed(Test.java:215)
>           at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
>           at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
>           at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
>           at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
>           at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
>           at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6216)
>           at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3265)
>           at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5981)
>           at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4583)
>           at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4413)
>           at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4556)
>           at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4220)
>           at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4150)
>           at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
>           at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2475)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4413)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Result extends javax.swing.JFrame {
float result;
String ID;
/** Creates new form Result */
public Result() {
initComponents();
}
public Result(float res, String id)
{
initComponents();
result = res;
ID = id;
Score.setText(res + "%");
try {

Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
String database = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quizdb";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "root", "1234");
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();


String sql = "select * from Result where ID = '" + ID + "'";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

Object[] newrow = new Object[5];
newrow[0] = "MAX MARKS";
rs.next();
for(int i=1; i<=4;i++)
newrow = rs.getString(i+1);
DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel)scoreTBL.getModel();
tm.addRow(newrow);
}
catch (Exception e) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"" + e);
}
}
```

coding of testJFrame

```
 import java.sql.*;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        String ID;
        String Subject;
        int index =1;
        int max =0;
        int result = 0;
        char [] answers;
        /** Creates new form Test */
        public Test()
        {
            initComponents();
        }
        public Test(String subject, String id)
        {
            initComponents();
            ID = id;
            Subject = subject;
            PrevBTN.setVisible(false);
            try
              {



            Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
            String database = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quizdb";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "root", "1234");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "select max(SNo) from " + Subject;
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            rs.next();
            max = rs.getInt(1);
            answers = new char[max];
            for(int i=0; i<max;i++)
                answers[i] = 'e';
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
            getQues();
             }
             catch(Exception e){ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+ e);
          }
    }
    private void getQues()
    {
        try
        {
        /*    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String database ="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=ELearning.mdb;";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); */
            Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
            String database = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quizdb";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "root", "1234");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "select * from " + Subject + " where SNo = " + index;
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            rs.next();
            QuesTA.setText("\nQ" + index + ".  " + rs.getString(2));
            a.setText(rs.getString("a"));
            b.setText(rs.getString("b"));
            c.setText(rs.getString("c"));
            d.setText(rs.getString("d"));
            a.setSelected(answers[index-1] == 'a');
            b.setSelected(answers[index-1] == 'b');
            c.setSelected(answers[index-1] == 'c');
            d.setSelected(answers[index-1] == 'd');
            e.setSelected(answers[index-1] == 'e');
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
         catch(Exception e){ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+ e); }
    }


    private void PrevBTNActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
            index--;
            getQues();
            if(index == 1)
                PrevBTN.setVisible(false);
            if(index < max)
                NextBTN.setVisible(true);
}                                       

    private void NextBTNActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
            index++;
            getQues();
            if(index == max)
                NextBTN.setVisible(false);
            if(index > 1)
                PrevBTN.setVisible(true);
}                                       

    private void bActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
        answers[index-1] = 'b';
}                                 

    private void ResultBTNActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        try
        {
         /* Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String database ="jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=ELearning.mdb;";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); */
              Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
            String database = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quizdb";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "root", "1234");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "select Result from " + Subject;
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            int i = 0;
            while(rs.next())
            {
                char ans = rs.getString(1).charAt(0);
                if(ans == answers[i])
                    result++;
                i++;
            }
            float res = ((float)result * 100 ) / max;
            sql = "Select " + Subject + "Result from Result where ID = '" + ID + "'";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            rs.next();
            if(res > rs.getFloat(1))
            {
                sql = "update Result set " + Subject + "Result = " + res + " where ID = '" + ID + "'";
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            }
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
            new Result(res,ID).setVisible(true);
            this.setVisible(false);
        }
         catch(Exception e){ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+ e); }
}                                         

    private void aActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
        answers[index-1] = 'a';
    }                                 

    private void cActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
        answers[index-1] = 'c';
    }                                 

    private void dActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                  
        answers[index-1] = 'd';
    }                                 

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please avoid SHOUTING.

Comment: If you need help with errors, please show the full error message and indicate which lines in your code are involved. Also, please try to format your code better so that it conforms to Java indentation standards and is thus easier for us to read.

Comment: sorry for that i am new

Comment: I have no error in my coding there is no red mark....while the application is running the person finish his test and when we click on show result in app it show the dialog box showig java.sql.sql.exception :Illegal operation on empty result set

Comment: I am not referring to error in coding, I'm referring to your error in logic. Your code is not working right, and you've got an exception showing -- post that information and post the line that causes it. In your catch block, print the stack trace via `e.printStacktrace();` and show that information here with your question, again along with the involved line numbers.

Comment: I have removed your shouting and got rid of the first sentence of your question that gives no useful infromation, but again, you should have fixed this, at least fixed the shouting, after reading the first comment that I posted. In the future please do so.

Comment: actually i didnt know that capital text mean shouting i used them to highlight .....i got what u r trying to say ....i am again checking my program from starting than if error continues i will post that

Comment: perhaps use the bold attribute on text to highlight. And minimize the amount to exceptional and few words if any (versus half of the post)

Comment: ERROR1: Illegal operation on empty result set.

Comment: I think now you can help me i used e.printStacktrace(); in catch block and i got that error @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this code

```
rs.next();
for(int i=1; i<=4;i++)
newrow = rs.getString(i+1);
DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel)scoreTBL.getModel();
tm.addRow(newrow);
```

to

```
DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel)scoreTBL.getModel();
while(rs.next())
{
java.util.Vector row = new java.util.Vector();

for(int i=1; i<=4;i++)
{
row.add(rs.getString(i));
}

tm.addRow(row);
}
```

**Edit:**

In your code you written like this

```
rs.next();
max = rs.getInt(1);
```

Change it to

```
if(rs.next())
max = rs.getInt(1);
```

If the above condition is true then only next statement is evaluated.

Comment: I am new so sorry for that

Comment: ITS still showing an error Satya

Comment: from where to get stack trace....i started using java only a month ago

Comment: post your error messages

Comment: Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\pc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\rehan vinay ip\build\classes
C:\Users\pc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\rehan vinay ip\src\Result.java:54: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method addRow(java.lang.String)
location: class javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel
tm.addRow(rs.getString(i));
1 error
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: this is error after that change ......i have no error in coding ....error cames while after finishing my test i click on show result the result frame doesnt open and a dialog box come showing java.sql.sql.exception :Illegal operation on empty result set

Comment: @rehan sorry I just edited my answer.

Comment: init:
deps-jar:
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\pc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\rehan vinay ip\build\classes
Note: C:\Users\pc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\rehan vinay ip\src\Result.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
compile:
run:

Comment: still showing the same earlier error but now there is no red marks in coding

Comment: program is running but that dialog box comes and result frame donot open

Comment: How many columns are there in table `Result`. @rehan

Comment: 5    ID,Ipresult,chemistryresult,biologyresult,physicsresult

Comment: post your error messages with line number. @rehan

Comment: I am not getting any error message i tried print stack trace but there it is not showing any error......can i send u whole program

Comment: ERROR1: Illegal operation on empty result set.

Comment: i have uploaded the correct error message now please look into it and tell  what i have to do @ satya

Comment: @rehan, error is in your `Test.java` at line `Test.java:292`.

Comment: @rehan, See my edit.

Comment: now my project is running completely fine there were problem in MySql quries...thanks a lot for your help